# Part 2 ERC-20 tokens parked (now trapped) in smart contract pre-Mist and after Ethereum Wallet sunsetting

Tags: erc-20

I have ERC20 tokens that have been trapped in a contract I created with the Foundation's Ethereum Wallet Jan 30th 2017. That was the first day I ever heard of Ethereum or tried to use it.
As stated in the similar thread I created, I was able to pass those tokens back and forth between two different contracts created under the same wallet. I used the GUI. It wasn't very difficult.
The blockchain grew to take weeks, not hours for download. It grew too large for my hard drive. And when I build a system that had space to hold the blockchain, it would get corrupt because of time sync issues. And as I was working to correct that problem, Ethereum Wallet and Mist were shut down and no longer developed.
I have 2 questions that I still need to understand because people have tried to help me. I'm just not a coder. I'm behind the learning curve.
QUESTION 1: Where exactly on Github would I find the ABI template for the contract that was created by the GUI, Ethereum Wallet. Because I am suspecting there might have been a now missing function called "transfer." If so, maybe transfer was only for ETH and not the tokens. I can see the ABI on Etherscan. But I wonder if the ABI of the GUI was different, somehow. I'm just chasing a rabbit with that idea
QUESTION 2: Isn't there an online web interface of Ethereum Wallet that is still the same desktop interface? I know I found it once, but I can't find it again. I'd like to try that again.
Thank you for your help. I need to get these tokens out of my contract. I've been waiting for gas prices to drop because it just costs too much gas to send transactions with MyCrypto  only to see nothing moves. I've been dead in the water ever since they closed down Ethereum Wallet and Mist because I can't move these tokens. I post transactions. They just don't work and show up as failed.

Comment: I am doing  something wrong with mist multisig on MyCrypto. I have ETH in the contract that should be spent for these failed transactions. But the ETH spent for the failed transactions comes out of the wallet that owns the contract.

Comment: Perhaps https://wallet.ethereum.org/, it was deprecated more than two years ago, since then is unmaintained. There's a migration guide but it is quite old in blockchain years https://wolovim.medium.com/mist-migration-patterns-6bcf066ac383.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to try and help me!